# How to use translate in d3 when data is loaded from external json

Tags: json, d3.js, nan, translate

I am new to d3 (still studyng the tutorials). I want to load an external json and perform some visualization based on the objects. It has lots of nested objects/arrays. I can access them but when I am using translate, it shows NaN.. I understand the error but what to do to solve it.. I am confused..
The code in d3:

```
d3.json('data.json', function (data) {

  var data1 = data.device.button.type;
  document.write(data1);
  var nodes = pack.nodes(data);

  var node = canvas
    .selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('transform', function (d) { return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'; });

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) {return d.r;})
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("opacity", 0.25)
    .attr("stroke", "#ADADAD")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2");

  node.append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return '<what I want as label>' });

});
```

As you can see I want to get the objects, place them in different places based on translate.. I am not getting the way to do that..
sample of json

```
"sourcefile": "Script", 

 "structure": {
   "Links": [
   [
    "step1", 
    "port1", 
    "step2", 
    "port2"
  ], 
  [
    "step3", 
    "port3", 
    "step4", 
    "port4"
   ], 

   ], 
  "device": {
   "step1": {
    "args": {
      "pin": [
        "XXXX", 
        100
      ]
    }, 
    "device_type": "console"
  }, 
  "lock": {
    "args": {
      "username": [
        "XXXX", 
        "test"
      ], 
      "address": [
        "XXXX", 
        "10.0.0.1"
      ]
    }, 
    "device_type": "Light"
  }
  ....
   ....
```

Error I am getting in console:

```
Unexpected value translate(NaN,NaN) parsing transform attribute. d3.v3.min.js:1 // not  able to handle d.x and d.y
Unexpected value NaN parsing r attribute. // idea is to make the circle based on the data in json, not static value..
```

Any help....

Comment: as a debug step place console.out inside .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});
so you can see that you are joining your data correctly

Comment: also share the structure your data

Comment: yes..I already use the console.log and it says: NaN...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that d.x and d.y are strings in a valid number format. Javascripts parseFloat() returns NaN if you pass something it can't convert into a number, like "a", or something else not valid.